# Kivy - Label text stacks until window is resized

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to Kivy and tried to write a little program which changes a label text to the text entered in a text box after a button is clicked.

My problem is: after clicking the button, the text from the text box is shown as the label text but unfortunately it stacks with the text entered and "transferred" before. Which means the newest text is in the front and the older text values are still visible behind the new text. After resizing the window the new text is shown correctly and the old text is gone.

main.py-file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class Screen(GridLayout):
    o_txt1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    o_lbl1 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def show_text(self):
        self.o_lbl1.text = self.o_txt1.text


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Screen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

my.kv-file:

```
<Screen>:
    o_txt1: txt1
    o_lbl1: lbl1
    cols: 2
    Label:
        id: lbl1
        text: 'lbl1'
    TextInput:
        id: txt1
        multiline: False
    Label:
        id: lbl2
        text: 'lbl2'
    TextInput:
        id: txt2
        multiline: False
    Button:
        id: but
        text: 'SHOW'
        on_release: root.show_text()
```

[image: screenshot of my code]

- as you can see, the text "lbl1" is still visible behind the new text

**My goal is: When the button is clicked, the text of "lbl1" should change to the text written in "txt1" without having to resize the window.**

Many thanks!

Comment: This works fine for me. I guess you are using an older version of kivy which might have any bug

Comment: Sorry, I didn't provide additional information that may be useful. I'm using Python 3.8.5 and Kivy 2.0.0 - unfortunately an outdated version of kivy isn't the issue.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error. Mine one is working just fine.